# Compilation of OpenCV / Eigen3 fail

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, eigen

I want to use OpenCV but I cannot compile it and I think It's because of Eigen.

when I use Cmake command, Eigen is found:

**> --     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.2)**

Whereas I have only Eigen2 on my computer. (Maybe It's an obsolete file but I don't know where it comes from).

Then, once Cmake is done I do

> make -j4

At 64% I have this following error:

/home/sl001093/opencv-2.4.10/modules/contrib/src/rgbdodometry.cpp:65:47: fatal error: unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions : no file like that
compilation aborted.
make[2]: *** [modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/src/rgbdodometry.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wFNh.png): *** [modules/contrib/CMakeFiles/opencv_contrib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2

Thank you very much in advance !

EDIT: here the output of the command line ccmake
[image: Output of the command line ccmake]

Answer (score 2):

- Use cmake-gui
- Set OpenCV source and build directory
- Configure
- In the Search box, type "eigen"
- Activate "WITH_EIGEN" flag
- Configure again
- A variable "EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH" should appear: click there and browse to the "include" subdirectory of your Eigen library.
  [image]
  Eigen is a header only library, so you don't need to install/build it: just [download a package](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (see "Get it" section on the right side of the page) and unzip it for the purpose of building OpenCV.

BTW, why are you using OpenCV 2.4 when there is already [OpenCV 3 available](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)? It might be that OpenCV 2.4 is not compatible with recent versions of Eigen, but I know as a fact that it is compatible with [version 3.2.2](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=News:Eigen_3.2.2_released!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you cmake gui with Ubuntu. I tried with ccmake but didn't find the EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH.
By the way I used an option to desactivate Eigen by building OpenCV...It's the solution I found but It's a pity. Before I never encountered this kind of problem. I'll download Eigen on the website in case I need it. thank you !

Comment: @lilouch I don't use ccmake, can you see there the `WITH_EIGEN` variable? Anyway, for cmake-gui, either try `cmake-gui` from command line, or try [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355565/how-to-install-latest-cmake-version-in-linux-ubuntu-from-command-line/595441#595441) to get the latest version of cmake and to have `cmake` and `cmake-gui` into your path.

Comment: Yes I could turn off it ! So instead on using ON I changed to OFF for the WITH_EIGEN variable.

Comment: @lilouch If you want to have Eigen, WITH_EIGEN should be on. If WITH_EIGEN is on, a variable EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH should appear, and then you should be able to set it. If not, I think you should append to your question your cmake output

Comment: @lilouch So, what happened? :)

Comment: I was able to compile OpenCV without Eigen but well I chose the "easiest way". I mean I don't like to not solve an issue^^ . I added a screenshot in my post to show you that even If I choose ON or OFF I don't see the EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH

Comment: @lilouch If you launch cmake-gui, and select your build directory,  everything will be much clearer. I have added a screenshot of what it looks like in my cmake-gui (Note: I have obfuscated my local path)